# how to remove version,hostname,name,tags,@version,prospector,source,host,type,offset

Tags: logstash

How to remove version,hostname,name,tags,@version,prospector,source,host,type,offset etc(all the default fields) in logstash output after filtering.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a ruby filter in the config file in order to remove the unwanted field(s):

```
filter {
  ruby {
    # do stuff
    event.remove(key)
    # do other stuff
  }
}
```

Here is the reference: [link to rubydoc.info](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/logstash-core-event/2.3.2/LogStash/Event)

Comment: please be clear,what you mean like in logstash config file in filter i should use ruby to remove that fields,    filter{ ruby{ event.remove(version)}},this is what i should do if i want to remove version in the output of logstash

Answer (score 0):

In the question you didn't mentioned about your filter. As an example I mentioned below answer.

```
    filter {     

        json{
            source => "message"
            remove_field => [ "message", "host", "path", "@version","type"]
        } 
}
```